# Master Exceptions/Crash Check

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I'm Writing a c# & MySQL database
I want to know it their is a way to do stuff after a Crash?
I know about the TRY command for small exceptions.
But I want code to try to run after a crash Like to Send a SQL string to try to log-out

The only way i can think of is to wrap the entire program in a big try and trow a custom Crash Warning, but it sounds kinda clunky?
Any other Ideas?

Comment: use finally statment after try catch

Comment: You can use `AppDomain.UnHandledException` event, it will be fired when process is about to crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Found this :
http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions

It seems to deal wit multiple treads too

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you could use try..catch, however, I think it's better to get the call stack ,thread...etc when exceptions occur, so I recommand you [dump tools](https://appcompanion.codeplex.com/)